# How did they know there was a 'dark side of the moon'?

Tags: dialogue, mulan

In Disney's [*Mulan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulan_(1998_film)), Shang sings "I'll Make a Man Out of You" during the training montage, in which are the lyrics:

> [You must be] mysterious as the dark side of the moon.

How did he know that there was a [dark (far) side of the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_side_of_the_Moon) that never faced towards the earth? Or was he merely referring to the part of the moon without sunlight reflecting off it?

Comment: Um... the dark side of the moon faces the earth all the time... that's why the moon goes through phases. New moon = dark side of moon. Dark side doesn't mean far side.

Comment: @Catija Nah. The far side always faces **away** from the Earth, and is colloquially known as "the dark side", not because it doesn't receive light, but because it is unknown to humans (impossible to see unless one goes and sends a spacecraft to go and see what it looks like).

Comment: @BWPanda The movie features the Imperial City, the character Mulan and the Huns - these are 3 ingredients that take place in the 1400s and 4-6th Century AD. In other words, it's totally historically inaccurate, so it wouldn't surprise me if this is another case of anachronism.

Comment: It is possible that they already know that there is a Dark Side to the moon since they always see the same side. That is why they consider the Dark Side mysterious. They never saw it. China already have, AFAIK, a good knowledge of astronomy.

Comment: I think @LeonX has the right of it, and should consider making an answer. The ancient Chinese may or may not have realized the moon was a *sphere* (I don't know that much about ancient China), but they certainly thought of it as a disk, at least.  Even disks have a flipside which they can't see (they would know they're always looking at the *same side* the way everyone always did - the visible features don't change.) Hence, although the the literal term "dark side of the moon" may or may not have actually been used in ancient China, the concept that the moon has a hidden side was knowable.

Comment: @Steve-O I think Disney animations make plenty of anachronistic references (just look at Genie from *Aladdin* for an extreme example: he's even making movie references), and this is probably one of those, except it was developed with the same logic as all the other historical inaccuracies in *Mulan*, which is: "Even though it is historically inaccurate, it works on its own as its own thing, and is plausible enough that it's not impossible or doesn't suspend disbelief to an average viewer"

Comment: @GhotiandChips Yes, there are a lot of anachronistic references in plenty of Disney's movies because they are mostly loosely based on Fairy Tales but with Disney's creative touch. They aren't exactly aiming for the history accuracy. Aladdin's genie was a entirely separate case. He was a master breaker of the fourth wall.

Comment: @LeonX All I can say is: "Exactly"

Comment: *Mulan* takes place in a fictional world - you can't even point what year it's set in, since the non-fictional elements it takes from happen anywhere between 400-1400 AD. As a consequence, it's basically pointless to look for how Shang's lyric is plausible. We can just say that it's plausible or even historically accurate, at best (though this would require citation), or just another Disney anachronism, at worst - either way, it seems to me a kind of moot question and discussion, considering the murky, fictional, historically inaccurate timeline we are working with.

Comment: I'd go with "dark" being the side away from the ***sun***, not the Earth.  You can see the dark side of the moon, partially, at least, whenever the moon is not full.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet That is not what "[Dark Side of the Moon](http://science.howstuffworks.com/dark-side-of-moon.htm)" means.

Comment: @LeonX - ah, so it is an idiomatic misnomer.  Fair enough.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Yes, indeed! :)

Comment: @PoloHoleSet You're thinking of the "night side of the moon".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making it into an answer as @Steve-O suggested.

It is possible that they already know that there is a Dark Side to the moon since they always see the same side. That is why they consider the Dark Side mysterious. They never saw it. China already have, AFAIK, a good knowledge of astronomy.

China, way before the Mulan story events, already had deep knowledge and were able to predict eclipses. In 120AD they were already able to tell that how the moon phases worked, so it was only a matter of noticing that there is another side to what they always see.

> The sun is like fire and the moon like water. The fire gives out light
>   and the water reflects it. Thus the moon's brightness is produced from
>   the radiance of the sun, and the moon's darkness (pho) is due to (the
>   light of) the sun being obstructed (pi). The side which faces the sun
>   is fully lit, and the side which is away from it is dark. The planets
>   (as well as the moon) have the nature of water and reflect light. The
>   light pouring forth from the sun (tang jih chih chhung kuang) does not
>   always reach the moon owing to the obstruction (pi) of the earth
>   itself—this is called 'an-hsü', a lunar eclipse. When (a similar
>   effect) happens with a planet (we call it) an occulation (hsing wei);
>   when the moon passes across (kuo) (the sun's path) then there is a
>   solar eclipse (shih).

**Source:** [Chinese Astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_astronomy)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, it's just a song lyric, but it's not indefensible.

The dark side of the moon is not called "dark" because anyone thought it literally lacked sunlight.  "Dark" in this expression *means* mysterious and unknown, as in "darkest Africa" -- somewhere where the light of understanding does not shine.

Chinese astronomers by the 5th Century AD certainly understood that the Moon was a spherical object phase-locked to the Earth, and therefore had a side that would never be visible from here.  Whatever they called it could be translated as "the dark side of the Moon".

There is another question about whether a low-ranking army officer would have used that phrase when talking to (or singing to) a group of recruits, but hey, it's a movie.

> "There is no dark side of the Moon.  It's all dark."
>   -- Roger Waters

Comment: Actually, I did a little research before posting my answer, and it seems like in China, they were only going to try to prove that the Moon was round after the 10th century.